# Scrapy returning "Last Modified" date error: "KeyError: 'last-modified'"/"ValueError: year 1610477971 is out of range"

Tags: python, datetime, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm attempting to return the "last-modified" date for a set of URLs using Scrapy. However, I'm returning an error that states: KeyError: 'last-modified'. Specifically, the following:

```
  File "C:\spider.py", line 460, in fetch_dates
    url_time = r.headers['last-modified']
  File "C:\structures.py", line 52, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'last-modified'
```

The code I'm using for this is:

```
  def fetch_dates(self, response):
        url = response.url
        r = requests.head(response.url)
        url_time = r.headers['last-modified']
        url_date = parsedate(url_time)
        for url in url_date:
            if os.path.exists('1url-to-date.csv'):
                append_write = 'a'
            else:
                append_write = 'w'
            
            with open('1url-to-date.csv', append_write) as url_f:
                url_f.write(url_time + "&,&" + url + "\n")
        
        return Item()
```

The code is also not generating my csv file or returning the information I need. Any suggestions? Thank you!

EDIT: I modified to the following;

```
    def fetch_dates(self, response):
        url = response.url
        r = requests.head(response.url)
        url_time = r.headers.get("last-modified", str(time.time()))
        url_date = parsedate(url_time)
        for url in url_date:
            if os.path.exists('1url-to-date.csv'):
                append_write = 'a'
            else:
                append_write = 'w'
            
            with open('1url-to-date.csv', append_write) as url_f:
                url_f.write(url_time + "&,&" + url + "\n")
        
        return Item()
```

But, now I'm getting this new error: "ValueError: year 1610477971 is out of range". Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: `url_time = r.headers.get("last-modified", str(time.time()))`.

Comment: You should check what exists in your `r.headers`, the error basically tells you that there is no such key in the dict

Comment: So if it's not available, I'd like it to return the current date. Does this mean it's not available for any of the pages it's seen so far? It should have crawled a couple hundred pages - not all produced by the same entity.

Comment: @ChristiFati, this change results in the following error, "ValueError: year 1610477956 is out of range". I assume it's just that the formatting is wrong - but I'm not sure how to fix it. thoughts?

Comment: the problem is simply that the dict `r.headers` has no key 'last-modified'. if you use `get` with a default, it uses that; here `time.time()` - which gives you Unix time, which in turn you can't parse as a string. instead, use e.g. `str(datetime.datetime.now())` as default for the get method.

Comment: What will this result in though? I'm not sure I understand - would you mind explaining a little further? I'm fairly new with python. Edit: I modified it to include str(datetime.datetime.now()) and it's resulting in this error: TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable

Comment: I mean `r.headers.get("last-modified", str(datetime.datetime.now()))` (you might need to add `import datetime` to your script) - datetime.now() just gives you the current date and time, str() converts it to a string (iso format with space as date/time separator).

Comment: Ah, I see - this is still resulting in a not iterable error. I'm starting to wonder if there's a more accurate way to collect the date of last update rather than using the "last-modified" date.